# How to automate Websphere MQ installation in windows?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have been working on MQ installation in last couple of weeks. Now I need to automate MQ 7.5 installation using chef or powershell scripts. MQ installation for unix I got this URL https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-chef through chef. For windows I am not sure how to automate ? Please guide me or send me any articles to do that. Thanks advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have you found the official docs on this?  If not, have a look at [Installing using a silent installation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sce.doc/q120000_.htm).  If you have, please update your question with details about which part of this isn't working for you.

Generally, Chef or Puppet just packages up the commands you'd type in by hand so once you have set up a response file, it's a simple matter to run the install programs with whatever options you need.

Please do however observe strict reboot protocol when installing anything on Windows.  Suppose for example something's been installed and not rebooted, then you come along to install MQ.  If the other app has a memory leak or other issue and your install fails, the last known good registry entry is the one that does *not* contain the last app.  When it doesn't come up after the MQ install then you will hear "MQ broke my app!"

So my general procedure for this is as follows:

1. Reboot the server.
2. Install MQ.
3. Turn off the MQ service.
4. Install the latest Fix Pack.
5. Reboot.
6. Set up the QMgr(s).
7. Reboot to make sure QMgrs can restart properly.

Of course, this assumes the necessary accounts and groups are already set up in Active Directory so that the installer is not required to create them.